# Perspective Projection of Ellipsoid to Ellipse: Solving for standard form ellipse equation

Tags: geometry

I am attempting to use perspective projection on an Ellipsoid to get the standard form ellipse equation:

$ x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$

I have followed the following paper:

https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PerspectiveProjectionEllipsoid.pdf

and wish to project the ellipsoid to a image plane a distance of 1 away and view point a distance of 2 away.

I will make the ellipsoid have the origin as the center. Thus my view point is set to $[0,0,-2]$

From the paper:

An ellipsoid is defined by a quadratic equation $x^TAx + bx + c = 0$ where A is positive definite matrix.

I create the A matrix as such since I have the ellipsoid shape and rotation parameters:

eigVal = 1./ellipsoidShape.^2;

A= ellipsoidR'*diag(eigVal)*ellipsoidR;

and set b and c to 0.

From here M is defined as:

$(b + 2Ae)(b + 2Ae)^T - 4(e^TAe + be + c)A$

Since my b and c are 0 my M becomes:

$(2Ae)(2Ae)^T - 4(e^TAe)A$

M = (2*A*e)*(2*A*e)'-4*(e'*A*e)*A;

Now I need a plane to project on, according to the paper I require:

Let u and v be any two vectors such that u,v, and n form an orthonormal system (all vectors unit length and are mutually orthogonal).

Where I assume n is the normal of the plane. Since I want a image plane distance of 1 away from the ellipsoid i.e the plane z=-1 I use the normal $[0,0,1]$ with a d of 1.

I then set u and v to $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$

The rest of the paper then becomes:

k0 = u'*M*u;

k1 = u'*M*v;

k2 = v'*M*v;

k3 = 2*(lambda - n'*e)*u'*M*n;

k4 = 2*(lambda - n'*e)*v'*M*n;

k5 = (lambda - n'*e).^2*n'*M*n;

P=[k0,k1;k1,k2];

[evects,evals]=eig(P);
evals=abs(evals);

beta = evects * [k3,k4]';
rho = k5;

phi = beta(1)^2/(4*evals(1)) + beta(2)/(4*evals(4)^2) - rho;
phi = abs(phi/(evals(1)*evals(4)));

ellipseShape = [sqrt(phi*evals(4)),sqrt(phi*evals(1))];

Using the computed ellipse shape I get a collection of $[0,0]$ pairs.

I noticed u'*M*n, v'*M*n, and n'*M'*n all equal 0 so I assume I am making an error in defining the orthonormal system including the plane normal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set both $b$ and $c$ to zero initially, you don’t have an ellipsoid; you have a single point.

Comment: In that case I should definitely define b and c. If the quadratic equation of an ellipsoid is  $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+eyz+fxz+gx+hy+iz+j=0$ then b would be $[g,h,i]$ and c would be $j$?

Comment: That’s right. Since your ellipsoid is at the origin, $b=0$—that’s the translation part of the equation—but $c$ definitely has to be nonzero. The equation you ended up with was basically $ax^2+by^2+cz^y=0$, rotated.

Comment: I've added $b$ which is either 0 or very close to 0 and $c$. The function works now, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If the ellipsoid is really centered exactly on the origin, $b$ can’t be anything but zero. If you’re getting anything else, it’s due to numerical instabilities somewhere.

Comment: BTW, I think it’s much simpler to find this projection via the dual to the ellipsoid than via the method in the cited paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that things went wrong right from the start when you set both $\mathbf b$ and $c$ to zero in the conic equation $\mathbf x^TA\mathbf x+\mathbf b^T\mathbf x+c=0$, making it $\mathbf x^TA\mathbf x=0$. For a positive-definite $A$, the only solution to this equation is the zero vector, so you collapsed the ellipse to a single point.